# Change index folder using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have this path  `www.exemple.com`

but my website is in `www.exemple.com/website/`

is it possible that when someone visits `www.exemple.com` they are redirected to  `www.exemple.com/website/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your site root .htaccess have this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /website/(\S*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule !^website/ website%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Comment: website is the directory ?

Comment: i was asking if "website" is  "www.exemple.com" or is the name of the folder

Comment: cai i use this RedirectMatch 301 /(.*) /website/$1  ?

Comment: just this <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
 

</IfModule>

Comment: ok try my updated code in root htaccess. Also provide full URL you're using to test it?

Comment: was my browser that memorized the wrong now i used other browser and worked